# Optionaly use eureka or kube services for nodeJS application depending on the environment

Tags: node.js, kubernetes, netflix-eureka

I have a nodeJS application running as a microservice and there are two scenarios:

1. when a developer is doing development on his machine. nodeJS application should register to eureka service and be able to communicate with other microservices without specifying URL or port to those services
2. when nodeJS application is deployed to kubernetes cluster, it should not register to Eureka and instead use existing kubernetes Services within the cluster to communicate with other services, again without specifying URL or port, only kubernetes service name

I was thinking of maybe using some env var that will tell the nodeJS service how to behave depending on the environment it is being started in

Comment: If the question is how you can add such environment variables in Kubernetes, have you seen this docs: https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/inject-data-application/define-environment-variable-container/?